# Is socket.io or webRTC , which is the best for peer to peer video chat?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, webrtc

I am trying to make website like [Omegle](http://omegle.com) where I have option for video chat.
But I am now confused about using socket.io or webRTC.

But my peer to peer text chat is based on socket.io.

please someone give me suggestion.

thanx in advance.

Comment: WebRTC is the only way to do anything peer-to-peer in a Web browser; WebSockets (and by extension socket.io) requires an HTTP server and therefore you cannot use it for p2p.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

socket.io (which is based on webSockets) cannot do peer to peer.  Chat is implemented using socket.io by having two clients connect to the same server and the server facilitates delivering messages between them. That is not peer to peer.

webRTC is sort of capable of peer-to-peer video sharing though finding the right peer to communicate and initially traversing firewalls with may take some help from another computer/server (depending upon network circumstances), but the data can be sent peer to peer once communication established.  See [webRTC on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/WebRTC/Peer-to-peer_communications_with_WebRTC) for details.

See this interesting article for a discussion of the "peer-to-peer-ness" of webRTC: [Get Over it: WebRTC isn’t Peer-to-Peer - It is, but it really isn't](https://bloggeek.me/webrtc-not-p2p/).

Comment: " two clients connect to the same server and the server facilitates delivering messages between them. `That is not peer to peer.`" -  thnx for this. I really was confused about this.